# Citing or embedding a summary of a movie review from another website on my blog. What SEO issues might I encounter?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, search-engines, user-reviews

I'm stuck because I want to show summaries of movie reviews from various sources on one page of my blog. Giving a backlink to the original link so that people can read the review on that website. Is it acceptable to show summarised or cite movie reviews and ratings from other websites? If not, how can I do it in the most acceptable way from an SEO standpoint?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a content license from the sites from which you are going to be using the reviews?

Comment: No. I was thinking to post summarised review and give a proper backlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to show summarised or cite movie reviews and ratings
> from other websites?

**Legally**, it depends. In most countries, it is **ok to quote/summarize when naming the source**. Especially if you provide a link, it is unlikely that anyone would have a problem with that.

> What SEO issues might I encounter?

Short-term, you might **lack unique content**. Especially in the beginning, I would make sure not to cite/quote too much but rather to **paraphrase**. While this would not create unique information, at least every paragraph would be technically unique content.

The main long-term issue you may face is that Google sees you as a site that just sends traffic to other destinations. In the past, Google has often tried to cut out such middlemen and send traffic directly to the destinations.

What you can do is try to **be an aggregator that provides actual value**. For example, by summarizing the reviews from multiple sources, including less common sources. If you only summarize the reviews from IMDB and RottenTomates, there is very little value for readers. But if you include genre-specific review sites or unstructured reviews written by journalists on news sites, you could create something that provides actual value.

> on one page of my blog.

If you look at successful aggregators that summarize content from other websites, you will see that about 0% of the successful ones are blogs. A **blog** is most likely **not the content format someone is looking for to get an overview of movie reviews**. You can, of course, start with a blog and earn some rankings. But you are unlikely to become the number one movie review aggregator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Coming to the "aggregator" part of your response. How can I safely aggregate content from these "review" websites and display it on the page? Doesn't this go against SEO? Also, will having .blog as a domain extension affect search ranking? Will my site rank lower than a .com?

Comment: "Doesn't this go against SEO?" No. it is all about the unique value you provide. There are many websites that do nothing but aggregating content that can be found on other sites. As long as you aggregate/summarize in a unique way, Google has nothing against that.

Comment: "will having .blog as a domain extension affect search ranking? " that is a separate question/thread.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Really thankful to you.